# Ubuntu 23.10 firmware update and battery can't handle more than few minutes

Tags: battery, firmware, 23.10

After the installation of Ubuntu 23.10 I did an update of a firmware of my Lenovo YOGA 720-15IKB laptop  but I am not sure that it was the firmware of the battery.
It was with this Ubuntu tool:
[image: Firmware updater]

I don't remember which one I updated

What is sure is that Windows 10 also has an issue with the battery and the laptop just turn off itself after few minutes of usage when it's not plugged.

So it's a firmware issue or a battery issue.

This battery I changed it myself 3 weeks ago but it was working fine, I could use it unplugged and it was working well. I bought it on this website:
https://www.laptopbatterie.fr/lenovo-batterie/batterie-portable-lenovo-yoga-720-15ikb-80x7.htm
And all the information I have is:

- SKU LFR1505

I don't know how to remove the update of the firmware I did on Ubuntu 23.10 to check if this bug with the battery comes from this update.

Or I don't know where to get the original firmware of this battery to install it back.

***EDIT***

I have found a command line info:

```
fwupdmgr get-history 
LENOVO 80X7
│
└─UEFI dbx:
  │   Device ID:          362301da643102b9f38477387e2193e57abaa590
  │   Previous version:   234
  │   Update State:       Failed
  │   Update Error:       failed to run update on reboot
  │   Last modified:      2023-10-15 22:08
  │   GUID:               c6682ade-b5ec-57c4-b687-676351208742
  │   Device Flags:       • Internal device
  │                       • Updatable
  │                       • Supported on remote server
  │                       • Needs a reboot after installation
  │                       • Device is usable for the duration of the update
  │                       • Only version upgrades are allowed
  │                       • Signed Payload
  │ 
  └─(null) Update:
        New version:      371
        Remote ID:        lvfs
        License:          Unknown
        Description:      
        The vendor did not supply any release notes.
```

What I understand:

- the update has failed but the actual new version now at 371.
- the modification date is 2023-10-15 22:08

Is this the battery or linked to the battery?

So I tried but with no success:

```
sudo fwupdmgr downgrade 362301da643102b9f38477387e2193e57abaa590
No downgrades for UEFI dbx: No releases found
```

**EDIT2**

I have contacted the support of this battery, followed each one of theses steps and the battery works back well!

1.Power off the system.

2.Disconnect any external peripherals (flash drives, printers, external hard drives) from the computer.

3.Disconnect the AC Adapter and remove the battery from it.

4.Press and hold the power button for 20 to 30 seconds to release the residual charge from the laptop.

5.Reconnect the battery and the AC Adapter.

6.Once the system is powered on and booted properly, re-seat the battery. Check if you still get the error or not.

7.Try and wiggle the AC Adapter cable and check if that makes a difference.

So maybe it was not linked to the firmware I updated from Ubuntu 23.10. I have no idea and not the skills to check this out.